# Progress bar not working when inflating View

Tags: android, progress

I have an AsyncTask to download some files, in onPreExecute I start another Activity that contains different stuff and a Progress Bar:

```
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, Explanation.class);
    mContext.startActivity(myIntent);

    View inflater = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.explanation, null);
    mProgressDialog = (ProgressBar) inflater.findViewById(R.id.Explanation_ProgressBar);
}
```

Here is the code in onProgressUpdate:

```
    @Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);

    Log.d("percent", Integer.toString(values[0]));
    Log.d("progress", Integer.toString(mProgressDialog.getProgress()));
}
```

In the Log I see that both the "percent" and the "progress" are increasing together till they reach 100%..
The problem is that the progressbar isnt increasing in the screen. Can anyone tell why?

Comment: What for do you start an activity from an AsyncTask? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have some pictures about the app, and it will take a lot of time to transfare the AsyncTask inside the other class.. The way I did it wont work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there because you have already started Explanation activity inside the onPreExecute() of AsyncTask. It should not be there.

As i don't know what are you trying to implement inside the Explanation activity, i can't suggest anything for the starting of activity inside the onPreExectute() of AsyncTask. And **Generally its not a good practice to start activity inside the `onPreExecute()`, instead we generally start new activity inside the `onPostExecute()`**.

Comment: I want to show the Explanation Activity while downloading.. Is there a way to update the ProgressBar while showing the Explanation activity?